# how to solve the default org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.index_jsp

Tags: java

when I use jstl tag

it always report an error,Like this picture,I don't know how to solve,please help me,I use idea,I use idea create SSM，but it always make a default,oh my god
 [enter image description here][1]
this is my code

Comment: Hi @yilian, you forgot to add the image in your question.

Answer (score 0):

index.jsp

```
%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: yilian
  Date: 2018/9/23
  Time: 14:59
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>依恋博客</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="<c:url value='/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css'/>" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<c:url value='/css/base.css'/>" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<c:url value='/css/home/index.css'/>" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<%@ include file="header.jsp"%>
<div class="nav-classfy">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-12 sidebar-offcanvas">
            <section>
                <h1>A path of programmer learning${name}</h1>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-12 sidebar-offcanvas">

            <c:if test="${!not empty catsListlist}">

            </c:if>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="container-content">

    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-8">

            <div class="row" id="row-content">
                @foreach($res_blog as $val)
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
                    <article>
                        <div class="atc-head">
                            <h2><a href='{{URL("blog/detail/$val->blog_token")}}'>{!!$val->title!!}</a></h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="atc-meta">
                            <label>
                                <span>作者:<em>{{$val->user_name}}</em></span>
                                <span>| <?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$val->create_time);?></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="atc-content">
                            <p>{!!$val->message!!}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="atc-link">
                            <label> <p><a class="btn btn-danger btn-default" href='{{URL("blog/detail/$val->blog_token")}}' role="button">查看详情&raquo;</a></p></label>
                        </div>

                    </article>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-4 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
            <div class="list-group">
                <a class="list-group-item active">阅读排行</a>
                @foreach($newest_blog as $val)
                <a href="{{URL('blog/detail/'.$val->blog_token)}}" class="list-group-item">{{$val->title}}</a>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-4 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
            <div class="list-group">
                <a class="list-group-item active">评论排行</a>
                @foreach($comment_blog as $val)
                <a href="{{URL('blog/detail/'.$val->blog_token)}}" class="list-group-item">{{$val->title}}</a>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                {{ $res_blog->links() }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<%@ include file="footer.jsp"%>
<div class="jump-top">
    <img src="<c:url value='/img/home/index/top.png'/>" onclick="top_top()">
</div>

<script src="<c:url value='/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'/>"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js'/>"></script>
<script>
    function top_top(){
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop =0;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/config/spring-mybatis.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- 日志记录 -->
  <context-param>
    <!-- 日志配置文件路径 -->
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:config/log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>60000</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Spring字符集过滤器 -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>SpringEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpringEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <!--spring监听器-->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <!--防止spring内存溢出监听器-->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- springMVC核心配置 -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
        classpath:config/spring-mvc.xml
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>jstl</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```